# EM algorithm for gaussian mixture model in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to implement EM algorithm for a clustering problem on a Gaussian mixture model.I generate a mixture of two gaussians and then try to learn the parameters of the two gaussians.I am following the tutorial given [here](http://mccormickml.com/2014/08/04/gaussian-mixture-models-tutorial-and-matlab-code/).The code of my implementation is given below:

```
clc;clear;
rng(1); % For reproducibility
MU1 = [1 2];
SIGMA1 = [2 0; 0 .5];
MU2 = [-3 -5];
SIGMA2 = [1 0; 0 1];
num = 2000;
X = [mvnrnd(MU1,SIGMA1,num/2);mvnrnd(MU2,SIGMA2,num/2)];

scatter(X(:,1),X(:,2),10,'.')

%%%initial values of parameters

%mu1 = [0.5 1];
%mu2 = [-2 -4];
mu1 = MU1;
mu2 = MU2;

%sigma1 = cov(X);
%sigma2 = sigma1;
sigma1 = SIGMA1;
sigma2 = SIGMA2;

%prior probabilities 
phi1 = 0.5;
phi2 = 0.5;

iter = 10;

   for i = 1:iter 

   %%%Expectation

   prob1 =   mvnpdf(X,mu1,sigma1); 
   %prob2 =   mvnpdf(X,mu2,sigma2); 
   prob2 =   1-prob1;
   probc1 = ( phi1*prob1 ) ./ ( (phi1*prob1)+ (phi2*prob2) );
   probc2 = 1 - probc1;
   %probc2 = ( phi1*prob2 ) ./ ( (phi1*prob1)+ (phi2*prob2) );

   %%%Maximization

   phi1 =  ( sum(probc1) )/num;
   phi2 =  ( sum(probc2) )/num;


   uvec1 = sum([probc1 probc1].*X,1);
   uvec2 = sum([probc2 probc2].*X,1);

   diff1 = X - repmat(uvec1,num,1);
   diff2 = X - repmat(uvec2,num,1);

   prod1 = (diff1')*(diff1.*[probc1 probc1]);
   prod2 = (diff2')*(diff2.*[probc2 probc2]);

   sig1  =  prod1/sum(prob1); 
   sig2  =  prod2/sum(prob2);

   %update
   mu1 = uvec1;
   mu2 = uvec2;

   sigma1 = sig1;
   sigma2 = sig2;

   end
```

The results are nothing close to the original,even after using the actual means and covariances on the algorithm.(On a separate attempt I used the commented values).
Now, I believe I am probably making an error in the matrix operations for multivariate Gaussian mixtures.Although, I get mean vectors and covariance matrices with correct dimensions, still the algorithm does not work.I have previously, used the same tutorial to implement EM for univariate gaussian mixtures.

Please help me identify any matrix operations or any algorithmic step that I might be doing wrong?

P.S. On a few iterations it also gave error in mvnpdf because either sigma1 or sigma2 wasn't square, symmetric, positive definite matrix.Is there any possibility that underflow at some stage is causing the whole problem?

**P.P.S** Okay so I am trying to correct the prod1,prod2 terms i think i should try doing it in two steps (i) covariance multiplication (ii) weighting and summing the matrices together.I am probably making an error in step (ii).

Comment: `sigma1` should be positive definite, so the error is before that. For example `sigma1 = (diff1')*(diff1.*[probc1 probc1])  * C` isn't correct to me, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#M_step

Comment: And `prob2 =   mvnpdf(X,mu2,sigma2);` was more correct than `prob2 = 1-prob1`

Comment: Okay, so in diff I am actually trying to subtract the meanvec for class 1 from the dataset. After that in prod1 I am doing the numerator of the sigma estimate.This is (diff)transpose * diff * [probc1 probc1] ,here I am multiplying diff( num * 2 dimensions) with [probc1 probc1] also(num*2 dimensions) which is the probability of each example belonging to class 1 multiplied with both components of each sample.Please tell me is this interpretation correct?

Comment: No, your estimation of sigma in the maximisation step isn't correct, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#M_step

Comment: then what is the correct one.please hint.I am totally stumped here.

Comment: I have seen the expression here, its the same as the one in the tutorial i am following as given in the question.I have coded it to the best of my knowledge.Please tell me the matrix operations I should do.Because I am obviously missing something about them.

Comment: When computing sigma1 you should have a loop `for i=1:2000   sigma1 =sigma1+ (x(i,:)-mu1)'*(x(i,:)-mu1) * esimatedProbabilityOf_x(i);   end;` and followed by `sigma1 =sigma1/sum(esimatedProbabilityOf_x(1:2000))` so that `sigma1` is symmetric and positife definite

Comment: Or you can use the [matlab's function](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cov.html) `sigma1 = cov(x(1:1000,:).*  repmat(prob1,1,4))`